# How to pass the url parameters to a mysql query as a tuple of strings

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I have an API endpoint as follows:

`http://127.0.0.1:5000/data?params= spanish, italian, english`

and this is my code in myflask.py:

```
@app.route("/data", methods=["GET"])
def my_api():
query = "SELECT * from tablex WHERE "
params = request.args.get("params")

if params:
   query += "col IN ('{}');".format(params)
```

What I expect in output is this query:

`"SELECT * from tablex WHERE col in ('spanish', 'italian', 'english');"`

But what I get is

`"SELECT * from tablex WHERE col in ('spanish, italian, english');"`

I also tried this:

`query += "col IN ('{}');".format(','.join(params))`
but didn't work

Comment: Don't do sql querries that way. Search the Web for "sql injection" to see why. Don't ever trust what you receive in a request

Comment: Thanks for your point. Do you have any suggestion or example I can prevent this injection?

Comment: because all I find is in cursor.execute() but I need to preper the query and pass to execute

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you :

```
languages  = ['spanish','italian','english']
string = ','.join(['%s'] * len(languages))
print("SELECT * from tablex WHERE col  IN (%s)" % string,tuple(languages))
```

But I would recommend that you change the SELECT for a PROCEDURE.